# Mr.Q : Make rainbow

Tags: riddle

There are seven cards with colors and numbers:

```
"1.blue"
"1.red"
"2.violet"
"3.orange"
"5.green"
"6.indigo"
"6.yellow"
```

Mr. Q said, "Make a rainbow with these cards."

Then, Mr. A placed the cards as follows:

```
"1.red"
"3.orange"
"6.yellow"
"5.green"
"1.blue"
"6.indigo"
"2.violet"
```

But Mr. Q said, "The positions of the two cards have changed!"

What is the correct order of the cards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mr. Q wants us to take.

> The nth letter of the color on a given card.

For example, the card "1.red" becomes:

> R, because that's the first letter in red.

Using this, the order needs to be:

> "1.**r**ed"
> "3.or**a**nge"
> "2.v**i**olet"
> "5.gree**n**"
> "1.**b**lue"
> "6.indig**o**"
> "6.yello**w**"

Answer (score 6):

The order that Mr Q. means is

> ```
>       "1.|r|ed"
>     "3.or|a|nge"
>      "2.v|i|olet"
>   "5.gree|n|"
>       "1.|b|lue"
>  "6.indig|o|"
>  "6.yello|w|"
> ```